# sql query: multiple rows append to show in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Following data

query:

```
Select EmployeeName from employee
```

Output

```
EmployeeName
------------
John
Micheal
Annie
Marry 
Scott
```

I want the above out put into following:

```
EmployeeName
------------------------------
John Micheal Annie Marry Scott
```

can any one guide to how to query (in sql server 2008) to show multiple rows data into one row.

Comment: is it that hard to include your table schema?, and sql for which database specifically?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use something like:

```
SELECT 
   STUFF((SELECT ' ' + EmployeeName
          FROM dbo.Employee
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using mysql, you can use GROUP_CONCAT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat, like this:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(EmployeeName SEPARATOR ' ') FROM employee
```

For other databases, you could try googling the name of your database and GROUP_CONCAT, you'll probably find something.